# Passing values from a userform to Flask

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

When I click the submit button on this simple example, I get a `Not Found` error on my page and nothing in console. What am I missing?

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
from requests import request

@app.route('/landingpage/')
def landing():
    return """<form action="print_output" method="post">
    Project file path: <input type="text" name="myform"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>"""


@app.route('/print_output', methods=['POST'])
def print_output():
    print(request.form['myform'])
    return "check your console!"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: bad url in the action param

Comment: @ioganegambaputifonguser that's one of the things wrong with the code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things need to change:

First, you need to import request from flask, that's the request that you will be receiving. The `requests` library is used to make requests.

Then, the form action needs to be pointing to the url you have on the second route: `/print_output`.

Another thing that needs to change is the `name="\myform"`, I removed the backslash on the form.

Also made the method capitalized: `method="POST"`

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/landingpage/')
def landing():
    return """<form action="/print_output" method="POST">
    Project file path: <input type="text" name="myform"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>"""


@app.route('/print_output', methods=['POST'])
def print_output():
    print(request.form['myform'])
    return "check your console!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```